org.springframework.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils : Cannot determine local hostname
I have tried UP to local in GCP Env with Spring Boot 2.7.8 and Java 11.
with this command I generated application_default_credentials.json and no issues this command
gcloud auth application-default login

then I run
mvn spring-boot:run

only i get this warning when I will UP spring boot app in local:
your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.


And
I got this error, I'm not sure this issue is related above warning?
org.springframework.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils : Cannot determine local hostname
or any ideas thanks in advance.
Trace:


Can you post the full stack trace?

I can fix, I have some VPN and some PROXY, in this case only added configuration in postman "Use system proxy" to Enabled. The rest to Disabled, then I have access health.  : )
